# Convert C_ulong_Array_40 to list or string in python?

Tags: python, arrays, type-conversion, ctypes

I'm trying to fight through some python code that interfaces with an hardware unit.

The unit have an python lib where I use an function called "readsub". But it returns the data in a format I get as "C_ulong_Array_40"

The code is simple:

```
err, length, data = card.ReadSub(2)
write_tofile(1, data)
```

But then I get the following error:
unsupported operand types (s) for +: 'c_ulong_Array_40' and 'str'

I assume I need to use ctypes for something, but it's all a bit of "magic" right now since I'm not that good in python yet.

What way can I convert the "data" to some format usefull? it can either be to an python list or one long string containing all data.

Thanks, br. Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I just learnt `C_ulong_Array_40` is a ctype array of datatype `ulong` with a length of 40.

FYI `c_ulong` is alias for `c_uint`, also `c_long` is alias for `c_int` https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).

To get your list of Integers;

`list_of_ints = [x for x in data]`

To get your list of Strings;

`list_of_str_ints = [str(x) for x in data]`

No strange conversions needed!

Comment: That's perfect!